# "If I knew what you want/wanted to eat tonight"

Tags: past-tense, conditional-constructions, backshifting

Context:

I am talking to my friends, trying to find out what she wants to eat tonight.

> "What do you want to eat tonight?"
>   "You know what I want to eat."
>   "**If I knew what you wanted to eat, I wouldn't be asking you what you wanted to eat**."

I am wondering about "wanted" and "wanted" should they be in the present tense? Maybe this is better:

> "If I knew what you **want to eat**, I wouldn't be asking you what you **want to eat**."

Answer (score 0):

Both **wanted** and **want** are grammatical there. Some speakers backshift to the past tense  in the *if*-clause, while others do not.

> I wouldn't be asking if I knew what you **want(ed)**.
>
> If I knew what you **want(ed)**, I wouldn't be asking.
>
> If I knew what it **is**, I wouldn't ask.
>
> If I knew what it **was**, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: What would you say?

Comment: I would backshift to **wanted** and **was**.

Comment: in this sentence: "If I knew what you wanted to eat, I wouldn't be asking you what you wanted to eat" Should the second sentence be backshifted as well?

Comment: @franziskabohn I would  say  "I would not be asking you what you **want** to eat".

Comment: Ok. But it I were to say: “If i knew what you wanted I wouldn’t be asking you what you wanted” —> would that make me seem like I know nothing about English?

Comment: @franziskabohn : That repetition of **what you wanted** is idiomatic in certain contexts; however, it would have some emotional payload, such as impatience, irritation,  vexation, or possibly the opposite, solicitude, if you were explaining yourself to someone who is slow to understand, and you were trying to calm them.  But if there were no such context, you *could* seem like someone who is  learning English, who does not know that the statement could end idiomatically with the phrase *....I wouldn't be asking*.

Comment: @franziskabohn : Referring back several comments: You could say *... I would not **have asked** you what you **wanted** to eat*.  But with **be asking** I'd choose the present, **want**, in the complement.

Comment: I think it sounds most natural to backshift to **wanted** and to leave the final clause implied: "If I knew what you wanted to eat, I wouldn't be asking."

Comment: Actually if you really want to emphasize your frustration, it would make sense to repeat the phrase without any changes: "If I **knew** what you wanted to eat, I wouldn't be **asking you** what you wanted to eat"

Answer (score -1):

Ok.

I’ll provide context.

My child is annoying me. 
I ask her what she wants to eat.

If I knew what you wanted to eat, I wouldn’t be asking you what you wanted to eat!!!